# How to clear a material-ui md-field component in Vuejs2?

Tags: forms, input, vuejs2, material-design, vue-material

I have a simple list component in Vue2 with the ability to add/delete items. My issue was that when I switched from a regular HTML  element to material-ui (https://vuematerial.io/), my input-clearing functionality broke.

This is what it looked like:
[image]

With the regular HTML element, I was simply targeting the element by ID (from within the methods of my component script) and assigning it an empty string to clear it, as so:

```js
      if (input.value !== '') {
        this.items.push({
          text: input.value
        })
        input.value = ''
      }
```

I found the solution, which I'll answer below, but again, my question was: How do I clear the field when using a material-ui  element? And the bonus question, which I haven't fully answered for myself: Why did it break?

Answer (score 0):

So, first the "how" to make it work:

I needed to set a "v-model" attribute on my  element (I called it "inputField"), and then initialize it to empty within the component's data properties, and THEN in my component methods "addInput" function, I had to set "this.inputField = ''" instead of "input.value = ''".

To illustrate:
[image]
[image]

So, that works. Here's the result:
[image]

Now, that just leaves the question of exactly how this all works, and why the method which worked for a regular HTML  failed on ? I'm not sure, and I'd welcome an explanation/education from anyone who can explain!

[Vue DevTools for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en) seems to give a hint:
[image]

"Mdclearable" seems intuitively to be related; this property is set to false. Is that something to do with it? I'm not sure.

Learning a bit more about [Vue's "v-model"](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Customizing-Component-v-model) and [reactivity](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties) was also helpful in solving this.

Again, additional comments welcome to help elucidate what is going on here! And I hope this Q&A will help someone else possibly avoid some frustrations in future.